# MapKit Standard Location Button. How do i add?

Tags: ios, swift

new to ios, looking to add the brand standard icons to my mapView.

Any ideas would be helpful.

These buttons to be exact:

[image]

Comment: `car.fill` and `location` in SF Symbols. The compass custom -- you'd have to render that yourself.

Comment: Yeah the compass is optional, just want to make sure the location button covers the different states eg tracking, Direction Facing and north facing.

Comment: To show the compass you simply need to set [`showsCompass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1451879-showscompass) to `true` or you can add an [`MKCompassButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcompassbutton).  You can add [`MKUserTrackingButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingbutton) for user tracking mode.  The car button is up to you